# Reading and Writing PHP operation in C#?

Tags: c#, php

I want to convert the following PHP operation to C# code, could anyone please help me to convert this to C#.

```
$swfaddr = $absolutepath."/components/flash/".$slug.".swf";
$swf = fopen($swfaddr, "w");
fwrite($swf, file_get_contents($game['swf_url']));
$thumbaddr = $absolutepath."/components/images/".$slug.".gif";
$thumb = fopen($thumbaddr, "w");
fwrite($thumb, file_get_contents($game['thumbnail_url']));
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `fwrite(..., file_get_contents())`? Is there something else you do with $swf and $thumb or would a copy(target, source) suffice?

Comment: Or can $game['swf_url'] be something like http://.... ?

Comment: Have you made an attempt yourself? Could you please post the result as well?

Comment: @VolkerK: I just want to copy a swf file from a web location `http://example.com/swf/mygame.swf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um google reading and writing files in c#.  pick what works for you.

The strings would be replaced with something like this.

```
StringBuilder swfaddr = new StringBuilder();
swfaddr.Append(absolutePath);
swfaddr.Append("/components/flash/");
swfaddr.Append(slug);
swfaddr.Append(".swf");
```

The file operations would use a FileStream to either read / write.

So for example (psuedo code)

```
File.Open(swfaddr.ToString())
byte[] file.readbytes
File.Create(newfile, byte[])
```

So Google reading and writing files to find what works best for you.  Most likely binary streams.